# javascript linking buttons to change colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Playing around with JavaScript for the first time and trying to get my website footer header and background color to change colour. I have created to buttons:

```
  <div class="styleBut">  
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">ReStyle</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</a>
  </div>
```

And the JavaScript code:

The problem I am not getting is how to link it back to my buttons, I am guessing a onclick , but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: please add your JS that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="styleBut">  
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-warning">ReStyle</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-warning" id="reset">Reset</a>
  </div>
```

instead of `#` in `href` ,change it to `javascript:void(0);` so to avoid default action of hypherlink.

JS :

```
document.getElemenentById("reset").onclick = changeBack
```

Comment: i dont understand the second bit document.getElemenentById("reset").onclick = changeBack do i need to put that in the javascript file?

Comment: what does it replace those. the actual function?

Comment: no. just add after function defination of changBack

Comment: Sorry i dont understand :0 i am getting so confused

Comment: So: function document.getElemenentById("reset").onclick = changeBack(){
 document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
 document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundColor = '#1a75ff';
 document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundColor = '#1a75ff';
}

Answer (score 0):

Give your anchor elements id attributes like this:

```
    <a href="#" id="restyle" class="btn btn-warning">ReStyle</a>
    <a href="#" id="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</a>
```

Then access them in JavaScript, like this:

```
    var restyleButton = document.getElementById("restyle");
    var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
```

Then "wire up" the elements to click events and the functions that should be called when the event occurs, like this:

```
    restyleButton.addEventListener("click", changeLook);
    reset.addEventListener("click", changeBack);
```

Comment: Could u look at my code again , i edited it and tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: @EagleBlind Please show the full html and javascript code. You've only shown 4 lines of html.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using this syntax it should normally work:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="changeLook()">ReStyle</a>
```

Also make sure that the elements that you are trying to change have an **id** :

```
<div id="body">
```

Comment: HTML inline event handlers are poor practice as they cause spaghetti code and create global function wrappers around the onXyz attribute value. Event wiring should be done via the DOM Event Standard.

Comment: @ScottMarcus OP said that he is using this syntax and that its not working properly. I'm just saying that it can work if he didn't mess up with the ids. I rephrased my answer a bit.

Comment: OP did not say he was using inline event handlers, he asked about onclick. I provided correct answer. You provided a way to work, but not correct answer.